# error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’: templated function that try to uses a template method of the class for which is templated

Tags: c++, templates

While playing with template and functors (not present in this question) I ended up with the following simplified problem.

The following code (available also [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=de9bb443e50b4a34f98b9308a109e0bc-9ac5ce49fb3bb81c20db0c664e0c63a1))

```
class A {
    public:
    template <class T> 
      bool isGood(int in) const {
      const T f;
      return in < f.value();
      }

};

class B {
    public:
    int value() const {return 10;}
};

template <class T>
bool tryEvaluator(T& evaluator, int value) {
    return evaluator.isGood<B>(value);
    }


int main( int argc, const char* argv[] ) {
  const A evaluator;
  evaluator.isGood<B>(20); //Seemingly no problem here
  tryEvaluator(evaluator,20);
  return 0;
  }
```

generates an error

```
main.cpp:18:34: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
         return evaluator.isGood<B>(value);
                                  ^
```

Is it it possible to perform what I am trying to do? Do I need to add for example some keyword?

And, side question, how should I better rename my question?

Comment: You have to tell the compiler you are dealing with a function template. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords). In your case, `return evaluator. template isGood<B>(value);`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Within a `template`, if you have a variable whose type is a function of your `template` parameters, or a type whose type is a function of your `template` parameters, this is known as a dependent type.

In your case, `evaluator` of type `T` has a type dependent on the `template` parameters.

When working with a dependent type, or a variable of that type, you need to give the compiler some extra help.

The compiler wants to be able to partially understand your code before it actually stuffs the `template` parameter in there in the instantiation.  By default, it assumes that everything *in* a dependent type is a value.

So `evaluator` is a dependent type, and `evaluator.isGood` is assumed to be a value, so `evaluator.isGood<B` is using `operator<` on `evaluator.isGood` and some unknown value `B` (which it cannot find: error), whose return value you then do `>(value)` on.  `B` is not a value (but is instead a type), so your code is in error.

You have to tell the compiler that `isGood` is not a value, but rather a `template` when it is used in a dependent context.

`evaluator.template isGood<B>(value)` is the syntax.  The `template` tells the compiler "while by default you'd assume a value is coming, instead a `template` is coming".  There are similar rules involving using `typename` within a `template` (but `typename` was earlier, so it goes in a crappier spot) to indicate what would otherwise be assumed to be a value is actually a type.

In your `main` method, the `evaluator` is not of a dependent type, so it doesn't need the help.

Comment: Very detailed explanation, thanks, now I understand what the compiler was understanding! :)

Answer (score 3):

Put a `template` keyword before `isGood`:

```
template <class T>
bool tryEvaluator(T& evaluator, int value) {
    return evaluator.template isGood<B>(value);
                     ^^^^^^^^
}
```

You must explicitly tell the compiler that what follows `evaluator` is a function template, because `isGood` is a dependent name. Otherwise, the compiler will be confused..